# Qt: Objects as member in other class crashes besides working second object

Tags: c++, qt, object, crash, member

my topic description might be quite strange but I am struggeling with some problem I do not know how to describe better.

I have 2 classes in a Qt project, one named "Admin", the other one is "Klient" - for our English speakers: "Client". Now my code was from a group of students. They created the class "Klient" where they did an instance in "Admin". Code below:

admin.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Klient.h"
[...]

namespace Ui {
class Admin;
}

class Admin : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
[...]

public:
    Klient klient;
    Klient klientb;
};
```

Working with the object "klient" works perfectly. Now when I add another instance "klientb" (no misspelling!) of "Klient"...

```
Klient klientb
```

...the program suddenly crashes... And I do not know why.
Any search on the web didn't give me any point where to find an error.

Class "Klient":

klient.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QDate>

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

[...]

class Klient
{
public:
    Klient(void);
    Klient(int fileid);
    ~Klient(void);
    [...]
};
```

klient.cpp

```
#include "Klient.h"


Klient::Klient(void) : style_coded(5) {}

Klient::Klient(int fileid)
{
    this->fileid=fileid;
}

Klient::~Klient(void) {}
```

Maybe anyone of you has a simple idea where to start? For me it seems very strange. Creating another object of the same class when I have the first one besides that working...

I also tried to create a new class with a different name AND: didn't work either. But when I say "Client client" in the constructor of class Admin, the program doesn't give me an error. Maybe I just don't get the simple fail...

Comment: You need to show at least the implementation of the `Klient` constructor, and at least how do you really create the objects. Now we don't know anything about it. In one word, you have to provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hello @VladimirBershov. Thank you for your reply. I think I got the failure. Somehow I didn't get all qDebug()-outputs that were necessary from the Admin constructor. So I did research and found a CheckBox that had somehow problems getting activated by the constructor. Now that was a "slightly" different cause than I had expected. I will manage to complete some code in the above example. Now another object from "Klient" can be created.